# how to find the first & last column number in a range after an event

Tags: excel, vba

I got the following code, which I use to select all columns that have white cells color in the range.
The range starts with columns that have non-white colors, in the middle has columns with white color, and ends with columns that have non-white colors

I need to find the column number in the range of the first and the last column with white color (that in this case are 3&5)

```
For Each WhiteCell In V_RangeName.Rows(FirstRowDataNr).Cells
    If WhiteCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) Then
        If V_FirstRowWhite Is Nothing Then
            Set V_FirstRowWhite = WhiteCell
        Else
            Set V_FirstRowWhite = Union(V_FirstRowWhite, WhiteCell)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

[image]

Comment: After the loop: `V_FirstRowWhite.Columns(1).Column` gives the first column. And `V_FirstRowWhite.Columns(1).Column+V_FirstRowWhite.Columns.Count-1` gives the last column number (if `V_FirstRowWhite` is a continous range).

Comment: Is `FirstRowDataNr` = 2? What is the final goal? To reference the range `G2:I2`, `G2:IlastRow` or `G1:IlastRow`?